# Type conversion issue when trying to output to textBox.Text

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the below code that is giving me the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 
> 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible'.'

```
textBox1.Text = Math.Sqrt(10.0 * (Convert.ToInt32(textBox2Value)) / 
    (Convert.ToInt32(textBox3Value))).ToString();
```

Textbox 2 (named `textBox2Value`) and 3 (named `textBox3Value`) values are whole integers and I assumed that evaluating it to textBox1.Text using ToString() would be sufficient, but it isn't.  I am not sure why.  I tried converting the textBox values to Doubles or Floats but it made no difference so I assume it isn't the formula itself but getting that value to display as a string?

Can anyone please assist with where I am going wrong?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] so we can see how `textBox2Value` (and other variables) are declared and assigned.

Comment: do you mean `textBox2Value.Text`? The error is telling you that you're passing a `TextBox` control to a method that expects a type that implements `IConvertible`. In the code you've shown, this can only be the `Convert.ToInt32` method.

Comment: Yes, that was it.  I was unaware you had to add .Text to the variables you were evaluating with.

Comment: `I was unaware you had to add .Text to the variables` You don't generally need it for most variables. You do need it for **controls**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are referencing the `Textbox` not its `Text`

```
var val1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2Value.Text);
var val2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3Value.Text);

textBox1.Text = Math.Sqrt(10.0 * val1 / val2).ToString()
```

Comment: Ohhhh, that was it!  Thanks.